# ffmpeg nvenc gpu utilization is less than 20 percent

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu

i use to convert videos by ffmpeg with h264_nvenc codec, currently i noticed that nvidia-smi command shows GPU utilization is less that 20 percent.

how could i utilize more GPU and fasten the process?

Comment: benchmark, find bottleneck, remove bottleneck

Comment: Also, show your command and complete console output. Hard to provide suggestions without knowing what command you're using.

Comment: my command is :ffmpeg -i NBIgKVIa8c.mp4 -b:v 2500000 -s 1920x1080 -vcodec h264_nvenc 1.mp4

Comment: show your ffmpeg params

Answer (score -1):

You can’t. Nvenc is not gpgpu. It is deticated silicon for accelerating some steps of the video encoding process. The bottle neck is in this component. Not in the vector units.

Comment: you mean -vcodec h264_nvenc does not use hardware to decode?

Comment: It uses hardware, it doesn’t use SIMD.